# LDAP filter by CN name, starts with

Tags: active-directory, ldap

We have a naming convention for Active Directory groups and want to access them with an LDAP query and filter, e.g.

```
AppX User
AppX Author
AppX Publisher
```

I'm trying to write a filter but can't seem to get anything back.. looks a bit like this:

```
(CN=AppX *,OU=Security Groups,OU=Group Functions,DC=blah,DC=blah,DC=com)
```

Is it possible to query groups by name and wildcard like this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try using `(&(cn=AppX*)(objectclass=Group))`

Comment: Is there any need to include the OU,DC path?

Comment: Nope, but you can use the path (aka base DN) to limit the scope of the search.